# RoR - SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: - Rails not appending _id to generated query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have two model objects LineItemClass and LineItemSubClass.  I am trying to add a new LineItemSubClass to a LineItemClass, and it is generating an SQL error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: line_item_sub_classes.line_item_class.
```

The correct query should be something more like `line_item_sub_classes.line_item_class_id`.

I used generate to create everything, so I am fairly confused as to why this is happening.  In researching the problem, everywhere else I have seen the SQL eception, the generated query had _id.  My only thought is that I am doing something wrong with resources that have multiple word names - are there any good docs on conventions for multiple word names?

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130905194234) do
  create_`enter code here`table "line_item_classes", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "code"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "line_item_sub_classes", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "code"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "line_item_class_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
  end

  add_index "line_item_sub_classes", ["line_item_class_id"], :name =>"index_line_item_sub_classes_on_line_item_class_id"
end
```

line_item_class.rb

```
class LineItemClass < ActiveRecord::Base 
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  has_many :line_item_sub_classes

  attr_accessible :code, :name

  validates :code, presence: true, length: {is: 2}, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}, uniqueness: true
end
```

line_item_sub_class.rb

```
class LineItemSubClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  belongs_to :line_item_class

  attr_accessible :code, :name

  validates :code, presence: true, length: {is: 2}, :uniqueness => {:scope => :line_item_class}
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}, :uniqueness => {:scope => :line_item_class}
end
```

offending code from line_item_sub_classes_controller.rb

```
class LineItemSubClassesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @line_item_class = LineItemClass.find(params[:line_item_class_id])
    @line_item_sub_class = 
      @line_item_class.line_item_sub_classes.
      create(params[:line_item_sub_class].permit(:code, :name))
    redirect_to line_item_class_path(@line_item_class)
  end
end
```

from the view, here is the form section - this is what creates the params right?

```
<%= form_for([@line_item_class,
              @line_item_class.line_item_sub_classes.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

the form tag in the output html is

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/line_item_classes/1/line_item_sub_classes" class="new_line_item_sub_class" id="new_line_item_sub_class" method="post">
```

The error is being generated by the controller, in line

```
@line_item_sub_class = @line_item_class.line_item_sub_classes.create(params[:line_item_sub_class].permit(:code, :name))
```

I tried splitting this into two lines, but it didn't help.  The update line threw a nil object exception.

```
@line_item_sub_class =@line_item_class.line_item_sub_classes.new
@line_item_sub_class.update_attributes(params[:line_item_sub_class].permit(:code, :name))
```

full error is;

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: line_item_sub_classes.line_item_class: SELECT 1 AS one FROM "line_item_sub_classes" WHERE ("line_item_sub_classes"."code" = 'A0' AND "line_item_sub_classes"."line_item_class" IS NULL) LIMIT 1.
```

I don't have a clue what the railsmagic is doing here, but I can't imagine why this query would ever be needed. It seems like it couldn't be run until after the record existed.

ANSWER - SORT OF...
I have fixed the error by changing the scope of the uniqueness validators in the LineItemSubClass model.

```
  validates :code, presence: true, length: {is: 2}, :uniqueness => {:scope => :line_item_class}
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}, :uniqueness => {:scope => :line_item_class}
```

is now

```
  validates :code, presence: true, length: {is: 2}, :uniqueness => {:scope => :line_item_class_id}
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}, :uniqueness => {:scope => :line_item_class_id}
```

This works. I can now create a nested LineItemSubClass without an error, but my RoR-sense is tingling.  It seems like Rails should be able to infer the name of the relevant database column when I scope uniqueness to an existing association.  Coding the name of a database column seems fragile.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Inspect the parameters in the line `create(params[:line_item_sub_class]...` and post those. My first, gut guess is that the parameters are invalid and they're passing in `line_item_sub_classes.line_item_class` instead of `line_item_sub_classes.line_item_class_id`. The reason I'm guessing this is because your schema and model relationship declarations look correct on the surface, so I don't think (at this time) that's the cause.

Comment: I had to do a little research to understand what you meant, so hopefully I have this right;  {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Lj8iy9VkzdWrvN4LyzXQ5BY7FdpV57l12Euqtch9RtQ=", "line_item_sub_class"=>{"code"=>"A0", "name"=>"Panel Box"}, "commit"=>"Create Line item sub class", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"line_item_sub_classes", "line_item_class_id"=>"1"}

Answer (score 0):

So, your parameters are:

```
{ "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"Lj8iy9VkzdWrvN4LyzXQ5BY7FdpV57l12Euqtch9RtQ=",
  "line_item_sub_class"=>{   // These are the only parameters that will get
    "code"=>"A0",            // considered when creating your new
    "name"=>"Panel Box"      // LineItemSubClass record in the DB
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Create Line item sub class",
  "action"=>"create",
  "controller"=>"line_item_sub_classes",
  "line_item_class_id"=>"1"  // But this parameter needs to be included
                             // needs to be included to set the
                             // line_item_sub_classes.line_item_class_id field
}
```

It looks like, in your controller, you're using `params[:line_item_sub_class]` to create the new record. So, I think first of all that you need to change your form so that...

```
params[:line_item_class_id]
```

...is actually under

```
params[:line_item_sub_class][:line_item_class_id]
```

That will take you part of the way there. However, I don't think that will necessarily fix your entire issue. Can you update your question with:

1. the SQL query output from this action being called
2. the filename and line number on which you're getting this error

If you want you can just post the entire rails log output when this controller action is called. It thank that will demystify it enough (I hope) to get it solved.

**Another way to say this** is that your form is passing in a structure of parameters that don't quite seem to line up with what your controller is expecting, and that's probably most of the problem. So, believe it or not, look at your view, the HTML it produces, and try to figure out why the parameters in it don't match what rails is expecting in terms of structure and naming. If you can figure that out you'll be most of the way there.

Comment: Have you tried `accepts_nested_attributes_for` instead of the way you're building your form there? See http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: Alternatively you could try adding a hidden field with the `line_item_class_id` in it, like: `<%= f.hidden_field :line_item_class_id, value: @line_item_class.id %>` - these form issues are a little tricky to troubleshoot when not in person, because it's hard to get a quick feedback look on the changes to the form, and how it changes the parameters.

Comment: I can see what you are saying about the malformed parameters, but it doesn't seem right.  Going back to the controller code, we first find the parent object, and that line of code is successful.  The parent_id should no longer matter.  The problem come when we create a new child object through the association; .build causes this SQL error, and .new results in a nil object.

Comment: sorry, above I meant .create, not .build

Comment: I agree, since you're building it off the relation - but where is that strange field name coming from then? I guess that's the question, yeah? Have you tried not building it off the relation just to see if it works? Something like: `LineItemSubClass.create(params[:line_item_sub_class].permit(:code, :name))` while setting the parent class id by hand?

Comment: look back to the question - i resolved the error - it was occuring in validation, not creation.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Sorry if I sent you on a wild goose chase.